# How to integrate Azure B2C User migration technical profile in a custom Sign In profile?

Tags: authentication, migration, azure-ad-b2c

I'm reading [Azure Active Directory B2C: User migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration) and having a hard time trying to figure out how to integrate the [Technical Profile described there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration#step-43-add-a-technical-profile-and-technical-profile-validation-to-your-policy) into my custom Sign In policy:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>

    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignIn">
      <DisplayName>Local account just in time migration</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">http://{your-app}.azurewebsites.net/api/PrePasswordReset/LoalAccountSignIn</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>

    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountPasswordReset">
      <DisplayName>Local account just in time migration</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">http://{your-app}.azurewebsites.net/api/PrePasswordReset/PasswordUpdated</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

I already have a custom SignIn policy called `SignInOnlyKMSI`. However I'm not sure how to hook that Technical Profile into my policy.

I opened an issue @ the repo:
https://github.com/yoelhor/Azure-AD-B2C-UserMigration/issues/2

however I don't think the repo maintainer is active.

They forgot to add the policy files to the repo and the explanation is not that good. It's missing some pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the latest version of the [user migration](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration). I moved to the Azure AD B2C community repo.

Yoel

Comment: Hey Yoel... if there was a note there in your original repo pointing to this new one that would have saved me some hours. :) By the way, the documentation @ Microsoft is outdated then because they still point to your old repo. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration#step-2-pre-migration-application-sample

Comment: [PR to fix sample URL](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/pull/37285) @LenielMaccaferri

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling with it I got it to work as expected...

In this part in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration#step-43-add-a-technical-profile-and-technical-profile-validation-to-your-policy):

> After you define the technical profile for your RESTful API, tell your
>   Azure AD B2C policy to call the technical profile. The XML snippet
>   overrides **SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email**, which is defined in
>   the base policy. The XML snippet also adds ValidationTechnicalProfile,
>   with ReferenceId pointing to your technical profile
>   **LocalAccountUserMigration**.

They tell you WHAT needs to be done but don't actually tell you HOW...

I figured it out. You need to add a new Technical Profile like the following one just below the other two in the same file `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml`:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <!-- <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="loyaltyNumber" PartnerClaimType="loyaltyNumber" />
  </OutputClaims> -->
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="LocalAccountUserMigration" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Note the `<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="LocalAccountUserMigration" />`. Just rename the 1st technical profile from `LocalAccountSignIn` to `LocalAccountUserMigration`.

Comment: Can you check our samples here? https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration and open an issue if needed.

Comment: Thanks spottedmahn... from your edit, I just learned that I need to use `lang-xml` instead of just `xml` when formatting the code. By the way: the new samples are different from that Microsoft doc I mention in the question. That doc is really missing some points. Looks like who wrote it didn't complete all the steps.